# Stop services when exit Application (swiping Application away in Android's task)

Tags: android

I have a service based on a check box in Activity(user can start or stop it).
Once it start, it will run in background, and should not be stopped when the activity is onDestroy().

However, I want to stop it when user swipes the Application away in Android's task, because this service need to restart when user reopen the App.

How can I do that? Is it possible to stop service in onTerminate() method in Application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I do that?

You can do it adding this on your `manifest.xml` on your `service`

```
android:stopWithTask="true"
```

If you want to controle it you can also do it on your `Service` adding the `onTaskRemoved()`

```
 @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    //STOP SERVICE OR WHATEVER YOU WANT
}
```

**If you use `onTaskRemoved()` don't add `android:stopWithTask="true"` because it won't be called***

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag to false when `onPause(`) or `onDestroy()` is called.Save this in `SharedPreferences`.Use this flag to check whether your app is running or not. Start your service only if flag is true.